# Passport Authentication Fails with associated model

Tags: node.js, passport.js, sequelize.js, passport-local

I made an addition to my database modeling where I wanted to attach my users to a specific company. I followed the Sequelize documentation to create a one to one relationship between user and company, but it appears that it has screwed up my authentication a bit as the introduction of the code has been sending every submission of a login to the `failureRedirect` portion of my authentication code. Has anyone run into a similar issue?

User Model:

```
var bcrypt   = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

var User = sequelize.define('user', {
    user_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    firstName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        field: 'first_name'
    },
    lastName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        field: 'last_name'
    },
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        isEmail: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    organizationId: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        unique: true
    }

}, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    classMethods: {
        associate: function(db) {
            User.belongsTo(db.Organization);
        }
    }
});
    return User;
}
```

Organization Model:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

var Organization = sequelize.define('organization', {
    organizationId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        field: 'organization_id',
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    organizationName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        field: 'organization_name'
    },
    admin: DataTypes.STRING,
    members: DataTypes.STRING
},{
    freezeTableName: true
});

    return Organization;
}
```

Database Index:

```
    var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
    var path = require('path');
    var config = require(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..','./config/config.js'));
    var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, {
        host:'localhost',
        port:'3306',
        dialect: 'mysql'
    });

    sequelize.authenticate().then(function(err) {
        if (!!err) {
            console.log('Unable to connect to the database:', err)
        } else {
            console.log('Connection has been established successfully.')
        }
    });

    var db = {}

    db.Organization = sequelize.import(__dirname + "/organization");

    db.User = sequelize.import(__dirname + "/user");

    db.FormApp = sequelize.import(__dirname + "/formapp");

    db.User.associate(db);
    db.FormApp.associate(db);

    db.sequelize = sequelize;
    db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

sequelize.sync();

module.exports = db;
```

Passport Authentication Routing:

```
var express = require('express');
var siteRoutes  = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var models = require('../models/db-index');

/*====  Passport Configuration  ====*/

// Serialize sessions
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log(user.user_id + "Serializing");
  done(null, user.user_id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user_id, done) {
  models.User.find({where: {user_id: user_id}}).then(function(user){
    done(null, user);
  }).error(function(err){
    done(err, null);
  });
});


passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy({
    passReqToCallback : true,
    usernameField: 'email'
    }, 
    function(req, email, password, done) {
        //Find user by email
        models.User.findOne({
            where: { 
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password
            }
        }).then(function(user) {
            return done(null, user);
        }).catch(function(err) {
            return done(null, false, req.flash('message', 'Email not found.'));
        });
    }
    ));




/*====  Index   ====*/

siteRoutes.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('pages/index.hbs');
});

siteRoutes.get('/flash', function(req, res){
    req.flash('test', 'it worked');
    res.redirect('/')
});

/*====  Login   ====*/


siteRoutes.route('/login')

    .get(function(req, res){
        res.render('pages/login.hbs');
    })

    .post(passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/app',
        failureRedirect: '/login',
        failureFlash: 'Invalid username or password.'
    }));



siteRoutes.route('/sign-up')

    .get(function(req, res){
        res.render('pages/sign-up.hbs');
    })

    .post(function(req, res){

        models.User.create({
            firstName: req.body.firstName,
            lastName: req.body.lastName,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password
        }).then(function() { 
            res.redirect('/app');
        //res.redirect('/sign-up/create-organization');
    }).catch(function(error){
        res.send(error);
    })

    });


module.exports = siteRoutes;
```